# Filter arrow function doesn't give a correct output

Tags: javascript, filter

```
const arr = [   { name: 'Dan', age: 33, color: 'red' },   { name: 'Mike', age: 21, color: 'blue' },   { name: 'Lance', age: 20, color: 'green' },   { name: 'Layne', age: 21, color: 'blue' },   { name: 'Dan', age: 18, color: 'red' } ];

const getUsersWithEyeColor = list =>
  list.filter((user, colour) => {
    return user.eyeColor.includes(colour);
  });


log(getUsersWithColor(arr, 'blue'));
```

I want to filter an array of objects dynamically, using an array function, but right now I am getting an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function takes two arguments so it should be: `(list, colour) =>...` and you need to compare the value so `.includes()` is not needed:

```js
const arr = [   { name: 'Dan', age: 33, color: 'red' },   { name: 'Mike', age: 21, color: 'blue' },   { name: 'Lance', age: 20, color: 'green' },   { name: 'Layne', age: 21, color: 'blue' },   { name: 'Dan', age: 18, color: 'red' } ];

const getUsersWithColor = (list, colour) =>
  list.filter(user => user.color === colour);


console.log(getUsersWithColor(arr, 'blue'));
```

`user` represents single element from `list`